# The "Esc" key in my bluetooth keyboard doesn't work, how to fix it?

Tags: mac, keyboard

I'm using Mac mini, and bought this new bluetooth keyboard. It's not Apple production, but has Apple layout. The other keys all work except "Esc" in the left up corner. Obviously it won't be handy if this important key didn't work. How to fix it, please?

Comment: I'd grab [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) from the iTunes Store & at least test the keyboard is sending something recognisable as an Esc. Should be key code 53 / 0x35

Comment: A few questions: Can we please have a link to the keyboard? Have you made sure this keyboard's esc key works, by trying it out on another computer? Have you tried using a different keyboard, but of the same model?

Comment: Hi Tetsujin, thank you for your guidance. I've just tried Key Code, and pressed "Esc" but nothing appears on the dialogue window, while space key, number keys all work very well. Seems like the system dosn't recognize "Esc" and from "f1" to "f12". Do you know how to make them match to the system, please?

Comment: I'd be tempted to take it back to the shop & swap it for a Mac-specific one. If they keyboard's not transmitting anything that Key Codes can see, then neither can the Mac.

Comment: Thank you, Tetsujin. It's bought in a supermarket, so seems not possible to swap. I need to give up on this : )

Comment: it is not a duplicate has it is not a question about original Apple keyboards. This is for cheap Chinese Bluetooth keyboards looking like the originals. They are meant for iPhone, iPad and Macbook and the top left key at the location of ESC is a HOME logo like on iPads.   I returned one the first time .. then I tried again to figure out you can simply do FN+ESC, well, FN+ the top left button.

Answer (score 4):

I have (likely) the same keyboard and solved the problem this way: I mapped <kbd>caps lock</kbd> to <kbd>esc</kbd>.

You can do this via **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Modifier Keys**. There, at *Caps Lock* select *Escape*.